# SQL Server and JDBC nested loops

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using SQL server for storing data and JDBC on server side coding. I have 1:N relationship tables and I want all data once in one select query. Currently I am fetching parent data first then for each parent data fetching it's child rows in loop. This will continue till four levels.

Any idea how can I write a single select statement so that get all data from all tables and store them into one large complex data type in Java?

Code Snippet:

```
for loop parent1{
          parent1 data into parent
          for loop parent2 where parent1.id = parent2.id
          {
             parent2 data into parent;
             // continues till parent4
          }
       add parent to parents;
  }
  return parents;
```

Comment: Please post your database schema.  Looping over results sets in a nested way like this sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Schema is like:
           Parent1 {
             id int PK;
          name varchar(255);

        }
    
        Parent2{
           id int PK;
        Parent1_id int FK;
        name varchar(255);
        }
        ..
        ..
        ..
        Parent 4{
           id int PK;
        Parent3_id int FK;
        name varchar(255);
        }

Comment: Even I have tried with cursor and user defined table type on sql side, but we cant define table type inside other table type in SQL :(

Comment: Typically heavy lifting of data should be done inside your _database_, not in your Java code.  Have you tried writing a query to accomplish what you describe in the question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes Tim. I have written Procedure call with cursor and I am able to get data what I want from multiple 1:N tables. Now I want that data to back to java code. I tried to use user defined TABLE type but problem is we cant create one TABLE type inside another which is possible with Oracle not with SQL server.

Comment: You don't need tables in tables for that, just join all relevant tables, make sure to sort by the discriminating columns that allow you to identify the individual entities and sub-entities. Then process the result set in order, creating a new (sub)-entity when the discriminating value(s) change. This is BTW also how ORMs do it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I agree but Parent1 will have multiple Parent2 rows, and then Parent2 will have multiple Parent3 rows and so on. Finally one complex object Parent1 made up of multiple Parent2 where Parent2 made up of multiple Parent3 etc.

Comment: That is not a problem, as long as you know when you'll have a new parent1, a new parent2 and a new parent3, etc. Yes you will have a lot of duplicate values for parent1, 2 etc: you will just have to ignore the duplicates, but as I said: that is how ORMs usually solve it as well.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRotteveel Do you know any blogs and code sample where I can refer.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't have any links to share.